# How do "Graceful Shutdowns" work when max instances = 1?

Tags: google-cloud-run

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract

> The container instance then receives a
> SIGTERM signal indicating the start of a **10 second period** before being
> shut down (with a SIGKILL signal). During this period, the container
> instance is allocated CPU and billed. If the container instance does
> not catch the SIGTERM signal, it is immediately shut down.

A: If I have **maximum instances set to one**, what happens when a new request arrives to the Cloud Run proxy **after** my container process catches a SIGTERM and is in the "10 second shutdown period"?

I assume that the HTTP request would wait until the shutdown completes, and then Cloud Run will boot a new fresh container to process the HTTP request?

Is this guaranteed?

I ask because my container assumes that it is the only process mutating a network
resource, and two containers would create a race condition (or processing one more HTTP request after the SIGTERM event).

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive

> However, you **might sometimes receive this signal before your container
> will be shut down** due to underlying infrastructure reasons and your
> container might still have in-flight connections. The graceful
> termination is therefore not always guaranteed.

B: How common would this be? Do containers always get a SIGTERM?

Could I just wait until `http_requests_outstanding = 0 AND SIGTERM_has_been_triggered` to run my shutdown code (at which point no further HTTP requests will be forwarded to the instance)?

Comment: In addition to @guillaume-blaquiere good answer, remember that Cloud Run is stateless. If your application requires state, such as **mutating a network resource**, then you have a design problem. Containers can and are launched at any time. Trying to detect and control that behavior will lead to chasing bizarre bugs. Either modify your design to correctly match Cloud Run's features or select another service. 2) How will you detect this: **http_requests_outstanding = 0**? The only time you can count on your code running is **http_requests_outstanding > 0** ignoring the CPU always on option.

Comment: 3) Also, you are not guaranteed to receive **SIGTERM**. Notifying your container is a best effort. Once an HTTP request returns, the container can be shut down at any time.

Comment: @JohnHanley Actually, **"mutating a network resource" is the recommended method for maintaining state on Cloud Run** (MySQL, Datastore, Storage etc etc are all "network based state"). `http_requests_outstanding = 0` can be detected by incrementing a counter when entering an HTTP handler. **When the SIGTERM event is triggered, it runs code** which can read/wait for that counter to reach 0.

Comment: I won't argue semantics with you. I can only offer tips and advice.

Answer (score 5):

If you received the SIGTERM, that means your container is out of the routable traffic. If a new request comes in, a new instance is created and the request routed to this one.

The SIGTERM is sent most of the time, when the autoscaler choose to offload the instance. However, sometimes, and it's totally fine, the underlying infrastructure doesn't choose to shut down, it's shutdown (case of outage, server physical failure, CPU disruption,... all those kinds of real/physical world issues). That time, the SIGTERM might not be sent.

Comment: If max_instances = 1, does this guarantee that I will never have two HTTP handlers active in two different containers? When a new instance is created does it wait for a) the previous HTTP handler to finish, b) the SIGTERM event handler to finish, or both?

Comment: Normally, an instance is shutdown after 15 minutes of unused (the latest request processing has been finished 15 minutes before the SIGTERM). Therefore, you can't have dual processing. However, you can have the case when you deploy a new version. The old version receive a request and process it. You deploy a new version and the old version is put out of traffic routing, but the request processing continue on it. Only the new request will be routed to the new version.